# Why is Merge Sort Worst Case Omega(nlog(n)) too?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, mergesort

Recently I came across this statement:

> MergeSort worst case is both O(n*log(n)) and Omega(n*log(n)) - and thus is also Ө(nlog(n)).

I am unsure of how the *Omega(n*log(n)) in the **Worst Case** comes about. What is the intuitive / Mathematical Reasoning behind it ?

I understand that for the Worst Case, maximum comparisons are made during a merge step and I am able to vigourlously prove this.

Hence, O(nlog(n)) is understandable to me as this is the worst performance of the algorithm, but I am unsure of the reasoning for Omega(nlog(n)) in the Worst Case.

I know that we do not define Worst Case as Big-Oh, Best Case as Omega and Theta as the Average, but treat these notations so long they fit the mathematical definitions.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge sort running time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926893/merge-sort-running-time)

Comment: The worst case of any comparison sort is Omega(n log n). It's one of the most well-known statements of theoretical computer science, and usually proved by showing the number of comparisons in the worst case is at least log_2(n!) = Theta(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

The merge sort algorithm -- in its standard form -- does not benefit from any kind of specific order that the input may have.

Irrespective of how the input is ordered, a standard merge sort algorithm will partition the array into the smallest subarrays of size one and then merge adjacent pairs of sorted partitions into a sorted, merged partition.

The partitioning phases do not look at the content of the arrays being partitioned, so it always proceeds the same way no matter how the input array was ordered. There is no notion of worst or best case here, as it is only influenced by the value of .

The merging phases will make O() comparisons where  is the size of one of the two subarrays being merged (they are equal in size give or take one). This step cannot be done with *sub*linear time complexity as *each value* in at least one of the two partitions is compared with another value *at least once*. Even in a "best case" where the input was already sorted, the merge algorithm will first compare the left-most values of both partitions and after than the second value of the first partition with still the first value of the second partition,...etc, so comparing all values from the first partition with the first one of the second partition.

We could also add that in standard implementations of merge sort, the merge phase actually populates a *new*, temporary array, and once the merge is complete the values of that temporary array are copied back into the input array being sorted. Also that copying necessarily has a O() time complexity for each merge, irrespective of the *values* being copied.

And so the number of comparisons and number of copied values will in total will be Ω(log).

#### Variants

Having said that, there are many variants of merge sort. We could for instance add a simple comparison before actually starting a merge phase: first compare the greatest (right-most) value of the first partition with the least (left-most) value of the second partition (these values are adjacent). If they are in their proper order, no merge needs to happen: the combined partition is already sorted.

With this little change the overal complexity does not change in the worst case, but the best case now becomes O(), i.e. when the input is already sorted.

Comment: *The merging phases will make O() comparisons where  is the size of one of the two subarrays being merged* More precisely: depending on the distribution of values, the number of comparisons varies between **n/2** to **n-1** where **n** is the length of the combined slices being merged. This boils down to *O(n)* in all cases